# What's the best way to load a VERY big txt file into R?

Tags: r

I have a big .txt file that I've downloaded from a website. It contains roughly 55 million rows.

I need to work with this data in R and I'm trying to figure out how to get the data in to a data frame in R.

This is what I'm using so far:

```
US_Citations_1 <- read.table( "201709_US_Citations_3.txt", header= TRUE, sep="|", as.is=FALSE, na.strings="NA", colClasses=NA, nrows=5000000, skip=0, fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, comment.char="", allowEscapes=FALSE, flush=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, fileEncoding="", encoding="unknown")

US_Citations_2 <- read.table( "201709_US_Citations_3.txt", header= FALSE, sep="|", as.is=FALSE, na.strings="NA", colClasses=NA, nrows=5000000, skip=5000001, fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=TRUE, comment.char="", allowEscapes=FALSE, flush=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, fileEncoding="", encoding="unknown")
```

I've basically divided the file in to smaller segmets (trying to import the entire file renders an error).

So The first code opens 5 million rows, the next file opens the next 5 million rows (nrows=5000000, skip=5000001), and then I have 11 more commands that each generate 5 million rows.

The idea was that once all 11 data frames have been imported, I'll use a simple rbind command to merge them all into one big frame.

My problem is that I cannot load the last 10 million rows. Even when I set it to just import 10 rows, it seems to get stuck and just work indefinitely.

Is there any other solutions you may have? Thank you.

Comment: try with `fread` from `data.table`

Comment: Why are you reading the data in chunks? If you cannot import 10 rows, then there's something else the problem and you should sort it first.

Comment: @denis Is the command called fread? I wasn't able to find the command in the package data.table.

Comment: Relevant: https://community.rstudio.com/t/large-csv-census-files-in-tidyverse/1725/12 | https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/8d9s7z/importing_a_16_million_row_csv_file_into_r_anyone/

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The first 9 codes working fine and were able to import the data, but it stopped working on the 10th code and I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: How is your memory usage? Is perhaps RAM full and system started using swap?

Comment: [chunked](https://github.com/edwindj/chunked) or [Apache Drill](https://rud.is/books/drill-sergeant-rstats/) may be helpful, but it sounds like you're generally going to have to be mindful of memory.